# Inconsistency of target link for "User was removed"

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app, deleted-accounts

Recently I've got rep change because some user removes his own account:

> [image: user was removed]

Tapping on this link in web refers me to [**reputation tab of the my profile page**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=reputation) on selected site.

Tapping in the iOS app leads to opening **all users tab** on selected site:

> [image: ios]

Tapping in the Android app leads to opening a page of the [**all users sorted by reputation**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/?tab=reputation) on selected site in the browser. Despite of the existence corresponding page in the app.

---

- App Version: 1.6.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

---

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1635123498b3d)

Comment: Testing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation

Comment: Not sure what's going on here.  The API is calling code that should generate the correct URL.  Will have to debug further.

Comment: @Brian have you debugged this by any chance?